# Errores de compilación con Xcode al clonar repositorio

Tags: swift, xcode

soy nuevo en Swift y Xcode. Estoy intentando trabajar en un proyecto privado en Gitlab y sucede que al clonar el repositorio, intento visualizar la aplicación pero me tira varios errores para al final tirar el mensaje de "Build Failed". Mis compañeros han hecho lo mismo y les funciona perfectamente sin errores.
Tenemos misma versión de Xcode (12.5.1).
Mi versión de macOS es 11.5.2

He ejecutado el comando "git clone <repo>" para clonar el repositorio, luego "pod install" para instalar las dependencias. He probado borrando los archivos "pods", "Podfile.lock" y "project.xcworkspace" antes de instalar las dependencias, pero tampoco ha funcionado.

Estos son los errores: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por qué borras el `.workspace` si ese es el archivo que debes abrir?

Comment: Luego con el pod install se vuelve a generar el archivo. De todas maneras es una de las tantas opciones que he probado

Comment: Después de instalar los `pods` intentaste `pod update`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución fue especificar en el archivo podfile la versión exacta en ciertas dependencias que aún no han sido actualizadas en el proyecto, de modo que no se instalen en su última versión. Algunas partes del código requieren cambios si se actualizan las dependencias, por eso los errores que mostré en la imagen. Entonces la solución rápida es instalar las dependencias en una versión que sea compatible.

**Ejemplo:**

```
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn', '5.0.2'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '8.2.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Purchases', '3.7.3'
  pod 'PhoneNumberKit', '~> 3.3'
```